# Using diff with markdown

Tags: markdown, diff, pandoc

I write my academic work (some code and some equations, but mostly text) in `pandoc`-flavored markdown. Version control works fine, but I hardly ever get meaningful diffs: I use 80-character lines, for readability, and whenever a paragraph is reflowed, many lines change and `diff` is no longer able to keep track.

Perhaps this just means that 80-character lines + free text + diff is not a workable combination, but I was wondering if I was missing a preprocessing tool or trick that works well in this scenario.

Comment: Have you checked the `--strip-trailing-cr` diff arg (strip trailing carriage return on input). Maybe the `-Z` and the `-w` might help too.

Comment: I haven't, thanks a lot for the pointers.